# Update a concat statement from one table with values from another table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which includes a concatenatedTerm field which is based on several other fields. Depending on a specific value in the Name field the concatenation occurs differently e.g.

```
Update Table1 Set ConcatField = concat(Field1,' ',field2) where Name=1;
Update Table1 Set ConcatField = concat(Field1,' ',field2,' ',field3) where Name=2'
```

For arguments sake let's say Name=1 concats with `First` and `Last` e.g. `John Smith` and Name=2 concats with `Honorific` `First` `Last` e.g. `Dr. Joe Blow`

I'm trying to force that to happen now with a second table that has `Name` and `Concat` fields. The idea being I could make a record like

```
Table2:Name=1, Table2:Concat=First,' ',Last
```

and then a single update statement like:

```
Update Table1 as T1
Inner Join Table2 as T2
On T1.Name=T2.Name
Set T1.ConcatField=T2.Concat
```

Because Table2 already exists with other Name specific data, I thought this would allow me to simply add to Table2 how Table1 Concats update and not have to keep updating the Table1 Update Statement, just Table2 as I add to it anyway.

However clearly the issue is that the update statement is pushing in the actual string from T2.Concat e.g. ALL Name1 records simply get `First Last` as Concat value

```
=Concact(T2.Concat)
```

and still get the same error. So the question is how can I push the string value from Table2 into the Update Value of Table2 where it actually refers to fields in Table1?

**Added Table Examples** `*(note this is not the actual tables or data so I understand in this simple case the solution I'm looking for could be obtained a lot easier, just trying to add simple common table as example)*`

**Table1:**

```
+-----------+-------+--------+------------+
| Honorific | First | Last   | SearchTerm |
+-----------+-------+--------+------------+
| Mr.       | Joe   | Smith  |            |
+-----------+-------+--------+------------+
| Mrs.      | Jane  | Doe    |            |
+-----------+-------+--------+------------+
| Dr.       | Bob   | Rogers |            |
+-----------+-------+--------+------------+
```

**Desired Output:**

```
+-----------+-------+--------+-----------------+
| Honorific | First | Last   | SearchTerm      |
+-----------+-------+--------+-----------------+
| Mr.       | Joe   | Smith  | Joe Smith       |
+-----------+-------+--------+-----------------+
| Mrs.      | Jane  | Doe    | Jane Doe        |
+-----------+-------+--------+-----------------+
| Dr.       | Bob   | Rogers | Dr. Bob Rodgers |
+-----------+-------+--------+-----------------+
```

**Table2:**

```
+-----------+----------+----------------------+
| Honorific | FullTerm | Concat               |
+-----------+----------+----------------------+
| Mr.       | Mister   | First,Last           |
+-----------+----------+----------------------+
| Mrs.      | Misses   | First,Last           |
+-----------+----------+----------------------+
| Dr.       | Doctor   | Honorific,First,Last |
+-----------+----------+----------------------+
```

*Note that I really want the Concat to be First,' ',Last but the Table Generator did not like quotes so pasted w/o.*

So the idea is that:

```
Update Table1 as T1
Inner Join Table2 as T2
On T1.Name=T2.Name
Set T1.SearchTerm=T2.Concat
```

would be equivalent to:

```
Update Table1 as T1
Inner Join Table2 as T2
On T1.Name=T2.Name
Set T1.SearchTerm=Case
When T2.Name='Dr.' Then Concat(T1.Honorific,T1.First,T1.Last)
Else Concat(T1.First,T1.Last)
```

and result in the same output as Desired Output but instead it simple does:

```
+-----------+-------+--------+-----------------------+
| Honorific | First | Last   | SearchTerm            |
+-----------+-------+--------+-----------------------+
| Mr.       | Joe   | Smith  | First,Last            |
+-----------+-------+--------+-----------------------+
| Mrs.      | Jane  | Doe    | First,Last            |
+-----------+-------+--------+-----------------------+
| Dr.       | Bob   | Rogers | Honorific,Search,Last |
+-----------+-------+--------+-----------------------+
```

In other words it is pushing the actual string from Table2 into the SearchTerm for Table1 when I wanted it to populate the Concat statement with fields.

Comment: please show the exact error message

Comment: And show a sample of your data and the result you want obtain

Comment: @scaisEdge Ok I hope these edits helped thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstood you but are you trying to use column value as part of SQL query? If so this is impossible.

Comment: @RomanR. Pretty much yes; Instead of declaring the column value in the sql query, I'm trying to push it in with another. Taking it that is indeed impossible...